# Cast OpenCV-Matrix to vector

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I cast an OpenCV Matrix to an `std::vector` **for as many OpenCV types as possible** (e.g. `cv::Mat_<T>`, `cv::Matx<T,M,N>`)? The following does not seem to work as `cv::Matx` does not have a `begin` method:

```cpp
template <class T>
inline void foo(const T& data)
{
    using value_type = typename T::value_type;
    std::vector<value_type> v(data.begin(), data.end());
}
```

Comment: There is constructor of `Mat_` taking `Matx`, which is cheap operation when passing `copyData = false` as second argument. Then in both cases you can use begin/end to read data and fill vector.

Comment: Thanks @rafix07! Does the constructor `Mat_` also takes itself? I.e. can it be done on the generic template, without knowing if one passes `Mat_` or a `Matx`?

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestion of @rafix07 I found a solution:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <class... T>
struct make_void
{
    using type = void;
};

template <class... T>
using void_t = typename make_void<T...>::type;

template <class E, class = void>
struct has_iterator_interface : std::false_type
{
};

template <class E>
struct has_iterator_interface<E, void_t<decltype(std::declval<E>().begin())>>
    : std::true_type
{
};

template <class T, typename = void>
struct as_vector
{
    inline static auto get(const T& t)
    {
        using value_type = typename T::value_type;
        cv::Mat_<value_type> s(t, false);
        return std::vector<value_type>(s.begin(), s.end());
    }
};

template <class T>
struct as_vector<T, typename std::enable_if_t<has_iterator_interface<T>::value>>
{
    inline static auto get(const T& t)
    {
        using value_type = typename T::value_type;
        return std::vector<value_type>(t.begin(), t.end());
    }
};

int main()
{
    cv::Mat_<double> A(2, 3, 0.0);
    A(0, 0) = 0.0;
    A(0, 1) = 1.0;
    A(0, 2) = 2.0;
    A(1, 0) = 3.0;
    A(1, 1) = 4.0;
    A(1, 2) = 5.0;

    cv::Matx<double, 3, 4> B;
    B(0, 0) = 0.0;
    B(0, 1) = 1.0;
    B(0, 2) = 2.0;
    B(1, 0) = 3.0;
    B(1, 1) = 4.0;
    B(1, 2) = 5.0;

    std::vector<double> a = as_vector<decltype(A)>::get(A);
    std::vector<double> b = as_vector<decltype(B)>::get(B);
}
```

However, I was hoping for something simpler.